# Receive whole page without closing connection

Tags: c++, sockets

Please dont give too much importance to little fouls in the code, focus on the problem.

The code request the same page 10 times. It call recv until the buffer has zero bytes, to make sure i received everything. Problem is, when recv has zero bytes it closes the connection, meaning i only received the first page. I need to receive the whole page before requesting the next one.

How to receive the whole page and to know its the last time i should call recv without going to the zero bytes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
int main() {

    WSADATA w;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    WSAStartup(DllVersion, &w);
    SOCKADDR_IN u = { AF_INET,htons(80),0,0 };
    u.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.1.1.1");
    SOCKET e = socket(AF_INET, 0, 0);
    connect(e, (SOCKADDR*)&u, sizeof(u));

    string l="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.site.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

    char b[100000];
        int i,iResult,iError,error;
    ofstream z("pg.htm");

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        send(e, l.c_str(), strlen(l.c_str()), 0);
        do{

            clock_t begin = clock();

            z << b;
            memset(b, 0, sizeof(b));
            int iResult=recv(e, b, sizeof(b), 0);
                if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
                        int iError = WSAGetLastError();
                        if (iError == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                    printf("recv failed with error: WSAEWOULDBLOCK\n");
                else
                    printf("recv failed with error: %ld\n", iError);
            }

            wchar_t *s=NULL;
            FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,NULL,WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPWSTR)&s,0,NULL);
            fprintf(stderr,"%S\n",s);
            LocalFree(s);

            clock_t end = clock();
            double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            cout << time_spent;
            cout << "#";
            cout << iResult;
            cout << "#";

        }while(strlen(b)!=0);
        memset(b, 0, sizeof(b));
    }

}
```

Comment: You *really* should have checks for the return values of just about all function you call. Especially the `send` and `recv` function, as they will return how much was sent or received in that call, *or* (which is also important) if there was an error.

Comment: Agreed, I'll change this in my main code. But about the problem what do you think? I dont think its an error, since the code is working as it should, but something that is lacking on my knowledge of sockets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that the socket is *blocking* so if there's nothing to read then `recv` will block indefinitely and not return until it has either received something or detected an error.

On the other side, while your program is being blocked in the `recv` function the server will timeout and close the connection. That will cause `recv` in your program to be unblocked and to return `0`.

If you want to keep using the same connection you need to make the socket *non-blocking* and check for failures from the `recv` call. When `recv` would normally block it returns with an error (`SOCKET_ERROR`) and sets the error code (which you get from `WSAGetLastError`) to `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: Not sure how to implement it, but i did my best and edited the code in the main post. I tested it, and apparently i didnt receive any error, for every recv i received the message "The operation was completed with success". I think maybe the connection being closed after recv receive zero bytes is a default behavior for the code, not an error.

Comment: @JavaOdd Before checking for errors you must make sure that the functions actually *failed*. You do that by checking what e.g. `recv` *returns*. I think you need to find some socket tutorial as a good one should have explained all this.

Comment: In my knowledge i>0 buffer bytes, i=0 closed and i<0 error. If by returns you mean i=recv(e,b,sizeof(b),0), then it returns the number of bytes in the buffer and then multiple zeros, because its closed. It didnt receive negative/error. If you mean something else, i will search a tutorial, if you have one i thank you.